# Iterate through 3d numpy array and multiply each value with a caliberated value

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have a 3d numpy array like

```
[[[ 90 220 210]
  [241 409 310]
  [126 376 201]]

 [[280 357 162]
  [108 204 248]
  [376 259 344]]

 [[254 279 216]
  [338 376 102]
  [310 256  84]]]
```

i want to iterate over each element and do this condition. if the element is greater than 255 i want to do integer*(255/integer) and save it in the same place.

how can i achieve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't integer*(255/integer)  = 255? So am I right in saying that you wish to put a ceiling of 255 on the numbers?

Comment: Yes. I thought  doing that will not directly convert it into 255 but to a certain relateable value . but putting it as 255 is easier

Comment: Best to use numpy.clip() then.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

> if the element is greater than 255

```
over255 = arr > 255 # produces 3D boolean array
```

> i want to do integer*(255/integer)

```
arr[over255] *= 255 / arr[over255]
```

Although in the end perhaps you can just do one of these:

```
arr[:] = np.minimum(arr, 255)
arr[:] = np.clip(arr, None, 255)
```